# Assign a Static Elastic IP to Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How to create a Network Load Balancer with one or more Elastic IP addresses in front of the Application Load Balancer using AWS CDK?

This should allow having fixed IP addresses for the load balancer. The article [I need a static IP address for my Application Load Balancer. How can I register an Application Load Balancer behind a Network Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/alb-static-ip/) recommends this approach.

The CDK API manual does not cover this use case. The [`class NetworkLoadBalancer (construct)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.NetworkLoadBalancer.html) lacks a definition of the `SubnetMappings` property. This looks like an issue in the documentation or the library.

The code should be preferable in TypeScript.

Comment: You can use Global Accelerator to get static IP for your ALB. This does not require NLB. Also what is your current code and why it does not work?

Comment: @Marcin I don't have any code to show as I don't know How I associate an Elastic IP to Network Balancer I don't want to use Global accelerator

Comment: @Marcin if I use Global Accelerator, How I can I point it to my ALB in aws-cdk?

Comment: @AnwarJaved, I updated your question. Hope you do not mind. In a nutshell, they do not have any working examples in the AWS API documentation. And it seems like the functionality is missing and requires some workaround.

Comment: I do not think that we should close the issue because the solution is not covered in the official manual and requires some research.

Comment: @VictorSmirnov closed and mentioned its not possible till date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of assigning a static IP directly to your ALB, you can [link](https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/faqs/) a AWS Global Accelerator to your ALB and it in turn will give you two static ip addresses. It's like adding a layer 4 load balancer in front of your load balancer.

I did this and then added a CNAME with DNS validation that links to the Global Accelerator. I then added the certificate to the load balancer.

According to Amazon Q, as long as the Global Accelerator is not deleted the two static ip addresses are retained.

From this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/latest/dg/about-accelerators.eip-accelerator.html):
*The global static IP addresses provisioned by Global Accelerator remain assigned to you for as long as your accelerator exists, even if you disable the accelerator and it no longer accepts or routes traffic*

Some [code directly from the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_globalaccelerator-readme.html).

```
declare const alb: elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer;
declare const listener: globalaccelerator.Listener;

listener.addEndpointGroup('Group', {
  endpoints: [
    new ga_endpoints.ApplicationLoadBalancerEndpoint(alb, {
      weight: 128,
      preserveClientIp: true,
    }),
  ],
});
```

As a side effect and actually the main purpose, this can help improve the availability, performance, and fault tolerance of your application by directing traffic to the closest and healthiest backend ALB instance.

`preserveClientIp` added a X-Forwarded-For header and has nothing to do with retaining the static ip addresses.

Comment: But How we retain same ip on next deploy?

Comment: AWS Global Accelerator FTW!

Answer (score 1):

Before answering the question about the static IP address for the load balancer, I want to suggest an alternative solution.

## Alternative solution - register ALB with Route53

We can create a DNS record for the ALB in Route53 using CDK. The code is straightforward. Unfortunately, this solution does not work nicely if the DNS zone is not hosted by the AWS Route53.

```js
  // Create or import your hosted zone.
  const hostedZone = new PublicHostedZone(stack, 'HostedZone', {
    zoneName: 'your.domain.name'
  })

  const loadBalancer = ... // Define your ALB.

  // Create a DNS record for your ALB instead of the static IP address.
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-new
  new ARecord(stack, 'WebServerARecord', {
    recordName: 'www',
    target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new LoadBalancerTarget(loadBalancer)),
    zone: hostedZone
  })
```

## Issues with fixed address for the Network Load Balancer

At the moment of writing, CDK constructs do not have the option to assign a static IP address to the Network Load Balancer. There are several open issues on GitHub: [SubnetMappings support for LoadBalancer #7424](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7424), [Add support for SubnetMapping to Network Load Balancer #9696](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9696).

In a nutshell, using the `SubnetMappings` allows the load balancer to specify one or more Elastic IP addresses, but the [`NetworkLoadBalancer`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.NetworkLoadBalancer.html) class does not have the [`SubnetMappings`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-subnetmappings) property.

> [Network Load Balancers] You can specify subnets from one or more
> Availability Zones. You can specify one Elastic IP address per subnet
> if you need static IP addresses for your internet-facing load
> balancer.

Issue 7424 is more than two years old. Instead of waiting, we might want to go for a workaround if we must.

## Workaround to assign Elastic IP address to the NLB

We will register an Elastic IP address, create a Network Load Balancer and assign it the IP address. I also add code to import VPC and create a simple Application Load Balancer for completeness. Please, check the code below and comments on the code. Note that the network load balancer and the Elastic IP start responding with some delay after the stack creation.

```js
import { App, Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib'
import { CfnEIP, Port, Vpc } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2'
import { ApplicationLoadBalancer, ListenerAction, NetworkLoadBalancer } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2'
import { AlbTarget } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2-targets'
import { env } from 'process'

function createStack (scope, id, props) {
  const stack = new Stack(scope, id, props)

  // 1. Prepare required resources: import VPC and create simple ALB.
  const vpc = Vpc.fromLookup(stack, 'Vpc', { vpcName: 'BlogVpc' })
  const alb = new ApplicationLoadBalancer(stack, 'ALB', {
    internetFacing: false,
    port: 80,
    vpc
  })
  const albListener = alb.addListener('HttpListener', {
    defaultAction: ListenerAction.fixedResponse(200, {
      contentType: 'text/plain', messageBody: 'Hello World!'
    }),
    open: true,
    port: 80,
  })

  // 2. Create an Elastic IP address.
  const elasticIp = new CfnEIP(stack, 'ElasticIp', {domain: 'vpc'})

  // 3.1. Create a network load balancer.
  const nlb = new NetworkLoadBalancer(stack, 'NLB', {
    crossZoneEnabled: true,
    internetFacing: true,
    vpc
  })

  // 3.2. Add listener and target group to forward traffic to ALB.
  const nlbTargetGroup = nlb
    .addListener('AlbListener', {port: 80})
    .addTargets('AlbTargets', {targets: [new AlbTarget(alb, 80)], port: 80});

  // 3.3. We should create an ALB listener before creating the target group. This dependency is not added automatically.
  // https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/17208
  nlbTargetGroup.node.addDependency(albListener);

  // 3.4. Replace Subnets with SubnetMappings.
  // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-subnetmapping.html
  // We can have mappings for all public subnets. I did one for simplicity.
  const cfnNlb = nlb.node.defaultChild
  cfnNlb.addDeletionOverride('Properties.Subnets')
  cfnNlb.subnetMappings = [{
    allocationId: elasticIp.attrAllocationId,
    subnetId: vpc.publicSubnets[0].subnetId
  }]

  return stack
}

const app = new App()
createStack(app, 'StaticIpStack', {
  env: { account: env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, region: env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION }
})
```

The screenshot below shows the IP address association in the Console. You can add more associations to the `cfnNlb.subnetMappings` list. If you want to remove some, you must recreate the load balancer.

[image]